# C pre processor not processing header files includes in form #include <header.h>

Tags: c-preprocessor

C pre processor not processing header files includes in form #include . It gives error: No such file or directory. The files that are included in form #include "header.h" are pre processed properly. How do solve this. I am using command:

```
cpp -P -I.PWD file.c
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `-I./PWD`?

Comment: Which OS and compiler you use? If PWD means working directory, -I . could be enough, by the way. Also, check that these headers are actually located in that directory.

Comment: These headers are available in current working directory. -I. works for me. But the cpp command fails only for files with pattern #include <header_name.h>

Comment: And `<header_name.h>` is in the current directory? The one where you're in when you run the command? Then doing simply `-I.` should work.

Comment: yes the header is available in the directory. I manually changed <> to "". It gives preprocessed output. But fails if I revert to <>

Comment: Are you *really* using `-I.`, or are you doing `-I.PWD` as you show in the question? Those two paths are *very* different! `-I.` adds the current directory, and `-I.PWD` adds the (hidden) directory `.PWD`.

Answer (score 0):

`#include "filename"` is different from `#include <filename>`.
See ([What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)).  `

Gist: `#include <filename>` does NOT search in `.`.